# Is there a way to group values in python dictionaries and list?

Tags: python

I currently have a list of values which look something like this:

```
lst = [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy', 'date': '2022-01-30'}, 
{'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob', 'date': '2022-01-30'}, 
{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara', 'date': '2022-01-31'}]
```

How can I group it by the date?

```
[{'date': '2022-01-30', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy'}, {'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob'}]},
{'date': '2022-01-31', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara'}]
```

I have tried something with for loop but it doesnt seem to work for me

```
final_data = []

for i in lst:
    temp_data = {}
    if i['date'] not in temp_data:
        temp_data['date'] = i['date']
        final_data.append(temp_data)
```

Comment: Your input is JSON. You could use a package like pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a dictionary as output:

```
from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)

for d in lst:
    d = d.copy() # avoids mutating the original dictionaries.
    out[d.pop('date')].append(d)

dict(out)
```

output:

```
{'2022-01-30': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy'}, {'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob'}],
'2022-01-31': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara'}]}
```

If you really want your format:

```
out2 = [{'date': k, 'details': v} for k,v in out.items()]
```

output:

```
[{'date': '2022-01-30', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy'}, {'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob'}]},
 {'date': '2022-01-31', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara'}]}]
```

###### first part without defaultdict:

```
out = {}

for d in lst:
    d = d.copy()
    date = d.pop('date')
    if date not in out:
        out[date] = []
    out[date].append(d)
```

###### both parts in one shot:

```
out = {}

for d in lst:
    d = d.copy()
    date = d.pop('date')
    if date not in out:
        out[date] = {'date': date, 'details': []}
    out[date]['details'].append(d)

out = list(out.values())
```

Comment: can i do it without using defaultdict? or must I have defaultdict? am trying to do it without using any libraries

Comment: You can do it without defaultdict, just check if the key is present manually and initialize with an empty list if not. But defaultdict is just simpler to use

Comment: sorry im not sure how to do that. does that mean i set the '2022-01-30' as the key of an empty dictionary first?

Comment: Love the short move-key statement: `out[d.pop('date')].append(d)`

Answer (score 0):

The self-implementing way is using for-loop with adding to the desired structure.

You can also use the module from standard library [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), **when the input is sorted** (before).

#### Group by

You can adjust the example from docs for your case:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [
   {'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy', 'date': '2022-01-30'}, 
   {'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob', 'date': '2022-01-30'}, 
   {'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara', 'date': '2022-01-31'}
]
keyfunc = lambda x: x['date']  # extracting the key for sort and group

groups = []
uniquekeys = []

data = sorted(lst, key=keyfunc)  # required for groupby
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    groups.append({'date': k, 'details': list(g)})  # Store group iterator as a list
    uniquekeys.append(k)

print(groups)
```

Prints:

```
[{'date': '2022-01-30', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy', 'date': '2022-01-30'}, {'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob', 'date': '2022-01-30'}]}, {'date': '2022-01-31', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara', 'date': '2022-01-31'}]}]
```

#### Remove the key

Since your output in `details` is not just a grouped list, but has the key (used for group-by) removed, we need to adjust a bit:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [
   {'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy', 'date': '2022-01-30'}, 
   {'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob', 'date': '2022-01-30'}, 
   {'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara', 'date': '2022-01-31'}
]
keyfunc = lambda x: x['date']  # extracting the key for sort and group

groups = []

data = sorted(lst, key=keyfunc)  # required for groupby
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    # remove the key from grouped list
    removed_key = []
    for v in list(g):
        del v['date']
        removed_key.append(v)
    # add to groups  
    groups.append({'date': k, 'details': removed_key})

print(groups)
```

Prints desired:

```
[{'date': '2022-01-30', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Amy'}, {'Amount': 15, 'Name': 'Bob'}]}, {'date': '2022-01-31', 'details': [{'Amount': 13.5, 'Name': 'Cara'}]}]
```

Comment: I love `groupby`, but this requires a sorted input, which in this case adds unnecessary overhead ;)

Comment: NB. as said in my previous comment, `groupby` requires a sorted input, your code won't work if `2022-01-31` is in between the two `2022-01-30`